# Public Subnet is not created in one VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

I have created a VPC with CIDR 10.0.0.0/16. Then in that VPC, I wanted to create two public subnets. So I have created two subnets with CIDR 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24.
Now I have launched two EC2 instances on these subnets but I am not getting public IP of both the Instances.  Please help me understand why I am not getting public IP of these instances and what should I do to get the public IP of these instances.

Answer (score 2):

To get a public IP address you either

- specify a flag on the subnet (in cli it's MapPublicIpOnLaunch, in the console I don't recall where) you want a public address by default on the EC2 instances
- explicitly  specify you want a public IP when launching an EC2 instance (on the screen you select the vpc and subnets)
- assign an elastic IP address to an instance

and do not forget to create a default routing on the subnet to the internet gateway